# Dynamic url rendered as a Document, api response. Angular

Tags: reactjs, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django + Angular, and I have a dynamic url which works for first time when load my product page. I specified as a dynamic url in Django too, so the url look like this "product/home/:productName/:productId". Everything definitely works but as a response when I reload my page, it gets plain API response document. So, I compared the request details and when reload it gets document and angular pollifies not working. I was searching around didn't found anything.

url.py

```
path('product/home/<str:handle>/<int:id>', ProductGet)
```

view.py

```
@csrf_exempt 
def ProductGet(request, handle, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

So, this code works for first time, but then when I reload seems it changes host to Django and I'm getting as a response, my API response.

[image: After reload page]
[image: Until for first time]

product-component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){

  this.productService.data$.subscribe(res => this.update = res)
  this.card = localStorage.getItem("card") 
  if(this.card === null){
  this.card = null
  }else {
    this.card = JSON.parse(this.card)
  }
 this.router.params.subscribe((param:any)=> {
  this.route = param.route
  if(this.route === "home"){
    this.route = {
      route: "/",
      name: "Основной"
    }
  }
  console.log(param)
  this.productService.getProduct(param.id, param.title).subscribe((res: any)=> {
    this.product = res
    this.selectedOption = res.options[0]
    this.selectedOption.selectedOption = res.options[0].values[0]
    this.selectedOptionName = res.options[0].values[0]
    this.mainImg = this.host + res.image
    this.isSale()
    this.src1 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.product.specs.iframes[0].src)
    this.src2 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.product.specs.iframes[1].src)
  
  })
 })
```

Comment: Does it happen when you press F5? Could it be related to Angular routing?

Comment: Yes, probably. But, the Angular source code worked when I was using Node.js and Express, and I able to reload page correctly. I added more details to question, maybe you can help

Answer (score 0):

So, something with browser and framework host where angular didn't understand a request.So the fix.

app.module.ts

```
import {HashLocationStrategy, Location, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

providers: [
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
```